# Buttons Overlays

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

The thing is I want to create an overlay for every meal we're selling and I want to activate it through the "Order" button but the problem is I can't seem to know how to target each specific button in order to give every button a diffrent overlay
    Here is  the html

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="MenuItems">



            <img src="ribeye.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="Sirloin.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="Skirt.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="T-Bone.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="TomahawkSteak.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="Flank.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="Chuck.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="BBQChuck.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>
            <img src="ribeye.jpg">
            <button onclick="on()">Order Now</button>





        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <div class="SideMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Menu.html">Steak</a></li>
                <li><a href="Chicken.html">Chicken</a></li>
                <li><a href="Appietizers.html">Appietizers</a></li>
                <li><a href="beverages.html">Bevreges</a></li>
                <li><a href="Desserts.html">Desserts</a></li>
            </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is supposed to be one of the overlays however I need to create multiple others and be able to assign them to any button of my choice

```
    <div id="over">


        <img src="r.png">
        <Button class="AddBtn">-</Button>
        <Button class="SubtractBtn">+</Button>
        <Button class="CloseBtn" onclick="off()">X</Button>




    </div>
















    <script type="text/javascript" src="MenuJS.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript :

```
function on() {
    document.getElementById("over").style.display = "block";

  }

  function off() {
    document.getElementById("over").style.display = "none";
  }
```

Here is  the CSS:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #over{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
  }


  #over img {
    position: relative;
    left: 35%;
    top: 25%;
    border: 2px crimson;
    width: fit-content;
    border-style: inset;
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
  }

  .CloseBtn {

  background-color: crimson;
  font-size: larger;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px crimson;
  left: 1500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 220px;


  }

  .AddBtn {
    background-color: crimson;
    font-size: larger;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px crimson;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 750px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 30px;
}


  .SubtractBtn {
    background-color: crimson;
    font-size: larger;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px crimson;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 760px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `this` as a parameter when calling the function, and access the element which was clicked via `event.target` within the function

HTML:

```
<button onclick="on(this)">Order Now</button>
```

JS:

```
function on() {
  console.log(event.target)
}
```

For the functionality you're looking for, your approach will depend on how you structure your HTML.

For the most basic approach, you can do the following:

HTML:

```
    <button onclick="on(this)">Order Now</button>
    <div class="over">
        <img src="r.png">
        <p>overlay 1</p>
        <Button class="AddBtn">-</Button>
        <Button class="SubtractBtn">+</Button>
        <Button class="CloseBtn" onclick="off()">X</Button>
    </div>

    <button onclick="on(this)">Order Now</button>
    <div class="over">
        <img src="r.png">
        <p>overlay 2</p>
        <Button class="AddBtn">-</Button>
        <Button class="SubtractBtn">+</Button>
        <Button class="CloseBtn" onclick="off()">X</Button>
    </div>

    <button onclick="on(this)">Order Now</button>
    <div class="over">
        <img src="r.png">
        <p>overlay 3</p>
        <Button class="AddBtn">-</Button>
        <Button class="SubtractBtn">+</Button>
        <Button class="CloseBtn" onclick="off()">X</Button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function on() {
  event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'
}

function off() {
  event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
}
```

This is utilizing [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) (because the next element after the button is the overlay) and [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) (the container of `closeBtn` which is the overlay)